# Not able to align items with justify-content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In a flex container, not able to align the items towards the flex-axis (when the flex-direction is column).

Please refer the code snippet below.

I would expect the result with the items aligned from the bottom (`justify-content: flex-end` supposed to be in effect)  .
But the items are displayed as if `justify-content: flex-start` is in effect.

Any idea where I am erring?

Taking hint from @Temani Afif's comment I could fix it.

I have to make sure the container height is 100%. Also height of the html and body elements are also 100%.

```
html, body{
            height: 100%;
 }
```

```css
html, body {
     height: 100%;
}
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-start { 
  justify-content: flex-start; 
}

.flex-end { 
  justify-content: flex-end; 
}  
.flex-end li {
  background: gold;
}

.center { 
  justify-content: center; 
}  
.center li {
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.space-between { 
  justify-content: space-between; 
}  
.space-between li {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.space-around { 
  justify-content: space-around; 
}
.space-around li {
  background: hotpink; 
}

.space-evenly { 
  justify-content: space-evenly; 
}
.space-evenly li {
  background: #bada55; 
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container flex-end">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: container height === height of all element ---> all the alignment are equivalent !

Comment: [Block elements consume the full width of their parent, by default. This behavior does not extend to height.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546152/3597276)